# Update table data when drop down selection altered

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently attempting to learn PHP and working my way through an exercise that involves creating a cinema booking system. At the moment I've made the following code as part of a table that allows the manager of a cinema to input details of new showings into the cinema system:

```
                "\n\t<td><select name='screen[0]' style='width:100%;'/>".
                "<option>";
                $sql0 = "SELECT * FROM tblscreen";
                $result0=mysqli_query($connection, $sql0);
                while ($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($result0)) {
                $screen = $newArray['id'];
                echo "<option> $screen </option>";
                }
        echo    "</select></td>".
                "\n\t<td><input name='seatsremaining[0]'/></td>".
                "\n\t<td></td>".
            "\n</tr>";
```

What I've written so far provides the user with a drop down select box, which takes as its source the name column of a database entity which holds all information about the cinema's screens. As you can see in the code, the next column of the table for inputting showing data is for recording the total amount of seats available for the showing. Currently this is entered manually by the manager. However, a value storing the total number of seats in a screen is stored in the same entity that holds the screen name in the database. I would like to write some code that would update the seats remaining column of the input table with the corresponding value from the screen entity as soon as a screen name is selected from the drop down list. Could anyone tell me what would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this after the event `onchange` of the select either refreshing the page or using ajax (I recomend the second option), something like this:

```
<select name='screen[0]' onchange="updateSeats(0)" style='width:100%;'/>
...
<input name='seatsremaining[0]' id='seatsremaining[0]'/>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateSeats(id){
    ... here you have to get the seats via AJAX php request against a callback function ...
}

function callbackFunction(info){
    id = info.id;
    seats = info.seats;
    document.getElementById("seatsremaining["+id+"]").value = seats;
}
</script>
```